# DNS Problem on new namespace on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kops

After create a new namespace, all deployments inside this new namespace don't have connection with the external world.

My env: Kubernetes 1.10.3 with Kops.

Comment: Danilo, need more information to help you. Which dns use?

Comment: Dns default from kubernetes. All namespaces are working fine with the external and internal connection. I only have problem when i create a new namespace. Maybe i need some kind of permission to have acess to kube-dns...

Comment: Can you post all the information on your question?

Comment: Yes, of course. I create a new namespace, after that i created a new nginx deployement and a new service to expose nginx. In this new namespace the network doesn't work property. I log in inside my nginx container and can't acess internet. I would like to know if i need to do additional configuration on this newspace to network works property.

Comment: Can you post the output of `kubectl -n kube-system get pods`?

Comment: Issue resolved.

A problem with calico-kube-controllers.

Thanks!

Comment: So how did You resolved the issue?

Comment: Recreating calico-kube-controllers deployment on k8s server.